# Android - Using bluetooth slows OS to complete crawl

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've been playing around with Bluetooth and built a test app that's almost identical to the functionality found here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection

I found that when I ran the app, I could talk to another BT device and communicate with it just fine. However, after closing the app my system would slow down to become almost unusable.

At this point, I started looking around at what resources weren't cleaned up. I overloaded the OnStop/onPause of my activity and in there I close my open socket. This had no effect...

So I'm wondering, is there something else I'm not properly closing or cleaning up that would be causing my AndroidOS to slowdown?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a Samsung device, there is a known bluetooth firmware bug for android 2.1 and lower.
I have encountered this bug on the galaxy tab and galaxy ace.
The workaround available is to disable and enable the bluetooth adapter when you have finished using it.